# Why different SPOT5 histograms from two versions of same SPOT5 raster?

Tags: qgis, histogram, spot5

I have encountered a, to me, strange behaviour in the histogram function of QGIS (2.2.0 Valmiera on Windows 7). Basically the same image produces totally different histograms.

I might have missed something fairly obvious, but I'm not able to find out what, and I have not been able to find any previous questions on the matter.

**Background**
I aim to do a "Black object subtraction" in order to correct for atmospheric noise in satellite images. Without getting too technical about that, I'm looking for the lowest pixel values with a frequency of at least 1000 pixels (a suggested method according to the literature).

**Problem**
When I calculate a histogram for my SPOT5 image, the maximum frequency of any pixel value is below 1000 (accept for 0, that indicates no data). I find that suspiciously low, as the image is 7900*7900 pixels.

*Comparison of histograms*
[image]

However, if I save the picture to with QGIS, just as it is, without any modification (see attached screen dump of save dialogue), I get a totally different histogram, that looks way more plausible to me (see image above).

*Save dialogue*
[image]

**Question**
How come that the basically the same raster produce totally different histograms? Is this a bug in QGIS? Faulty handling of images by me? Two different ways of rendering histograms?

Comment: Just a hunch: Is the original file a GeoTiff where the statistics have not yet been computed? You could check that under *Properties* -> *Metadata*

Comment: @Kersten Thank you for the suggestion. When I check the metadata there is a lot of numerical information about each band, so I guess that's not the case. It looks like this:

`Band
Band 2
Band No
2
Min Val
0.0000000000
Max Val
255.0000000000
Range
255.0000000000
Mean
35.3649441154
Sum of squares
68164335738.9491653442
Standard Deviation
32.9859098406
Sum of all cells
2215507654.0000000000
Cell Count
62647000`

Comment: the histograms look identical, except the frequencies on the right are about 16x higher - perhaps qgis is using a 1/4 resolution pyramid to compute the frequencies of the one on the left?

Comment: @StevenKay. Although I'm not sure if I agree that they look exactly identical, I guess you might be right. Seems like a plausible explanation.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not answering directly the QGIS issue about histogram, but rather questioning the method you used to select the dark pixel in the DOS method.

An absolute threshold based on the frequency of a value in the histogram will provide different results depending on the resolution, on the the number of pixels of the image, or on the number of bits used to code it. I would rather recommend a relative threshold based on the cumulative histogram : for instance 0.1% of the pixels (this value is just a guess, you might need to tune the threshold a little bit).

Comment: Thank you for the input @O-Hagolle. I think you have a good point and will do as you suggested! Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to vote up your answer. And as it is not an answer to the specifik question it unappropriate to flag it as the "correct" answer.